# In Order Traversal AVL Tree: Name not defined

Tags: python, recursion, avl-tree

I was just wondering would anyone be able to help me. I am trying to do an inorder transversal of an AVL tree. But I keep getting an error that my function name 'r_in_order' is not defined. What is happening here and what am I missing? Here is the code:

```
class Node:
    """ A node in a BST. It may have left and right subtrees """
    def __init__(self, item, left = None, right = None):
        self.item = item
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

class BST:
    """ An implementation of a Binary Search Tree """
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def recurse_add(self, ptr, item):
        if ptr == None:
            return Node(item)
        elif item < ptr.item:
            ptr.left = self.recurse_add(ptr.left, item)
        elif item > ptr.item:
            ptr.right = self.recurse_add(ptr.right, item)
        return ptr

    def add(self, item):
        """ Add this item to its correct position on the tree """
        self.root = self.recurse_add(self.root, item)

    def r_count(self, ptr):
        if ptr == None:
            return 0
        else:
            return 1 + self.r_count(ptr.left) + self.r_count(ptr.right)

    def count(self): 
        return self.r_count(self.root)

    def r_height(self, ptr):
        if ptr == None:
            return 0
        else:
            return 1 + max(self.r_height(ptr.left), self.r_height(ptr.right))

    def height(self): 
        return self.r_height(self.root)

    def r_in_order(self, ptr):
        if ptr != None:
            r_in_order(ptr.left)
            print(ptr.item + " ", end="")
            r_in_order(ptr.right)


    def in_order(self): 
        return self.r_in_order(self.root)
```

I am then testing the code with this:

```
import sys
from BST import BST

def main():
    # Read each test case
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    items = line.strip().split()
    nums = [int(item) for item in items]

    tree = BST()


    for num in nums:
        tree.add(num)

    print("Print the elements of the tree in order:")
    tree.in_order()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: The indentation of your code is broken. Please fix it.

Comment: @Bakuriu - Sorry my mistake, indentation correct now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`r_in_order` is a method of `BST`.  It can only be called on a `BST` instance (or on the class with an instance as the first argument), but in the definition of `r_in_order` itself, you try to use it without one.  So technically, it doesn't exist in the namespace you're trying to use it in.

Your function definition should be as follows:

```
def r_in_order(self, ptr):
    if ptr != None:
        self.r_in_order(ptr.left)
        print(ptr.item + " ", end="")
        self.r_in_order(ptr.right)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no general function **r_in_order**: you need to add **self.** to get a reference to the method you're already inside.  There's also a syntax error lurking in the print statement.  Try this:

```
def r_in_order(self, ptr):
    if ptr != None:
        self.r_in_order(ptr.left)
        print(ptr.item, " ", end="")
        self.r_in_order(ptr.right)
```

This runs, and yields the below (first line is input).

```
1 3 7 5 6 4 2
Print the elements of the tree in order:
1  2  3  4  5  6  7
```